# DatabaseException: Failed to parse node with class while add item to arraylist

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am fetching an array of data from Firebase database like below code and then I am adding one item to that array list

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("CategoryWallpaper").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    GenericTypeIndicator<List<WallpaperItem>> t = new GenericTypeIndicator<List<WallpaperItem>>(){};

                    List<WallpaperItem> yourStringArray = dataSnapshot.getValue(t);

                    WallpaperItem wallpaperItem = new WallpaperItem();
                    wallpaperItem.setCategoryId("Love");
                    wallpaperItem.setViewCount(-200);
                    wallpaperItem.setImageLink("https://www.google.com");
                    yourStringArray.add(wallpaperItem);

FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("CategoryWallpaper").setValue(yourStringArray, new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        });
                    }
```

my database is like below

[image]

After adding an item to the array list, I have done inspect code in debugging mode, I have seen below result - **the record was added in ArrayList with 580**

[image]

but I am getting an error at below line

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("CategoryWallpaper").setValue(yourStringArray
```

error is like below

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to parse node with class class .MainActivity$2$3
        at com.google.firebase.database.snapshot.NodeUtilities.NodeFromJSON(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.6:103)
        at com.google.firebase.database.snapshot.NodeUtilities.NodeFromJSON(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.6:28)
        at com.google.firebase.database.snapshot.PriorityUtilities.parsePriority(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.6:39)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.setValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.6:207)
        at MainActivity$2.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:151)
```

Comment: So what is basically the problem? What is the expected result?

Comment: New item is not adding in database and I am getting above exception

Comment: But why to add an array to the database and not add the items separately?

Comment: That structure is fixed before I have started to work on it, I cannot be changed :( I just need to implement feature,